# Prove that the stationary points of a cubic polynomial are between its zeroes

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polynomials

Given a polynomial $f(x)=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$ such that $a<b<c \;\&\; f'(p)=f'(q)=0$
Prove that $a<p<b<q<c$. All numbers belong to the real plane.

At first I attempted to solve the question by finding p and q by finding the derivative and solving it for f'(x) = 0 but I complicated the question even more.
When I look at the [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5L84w.png) of cubic polynomials, I can see that p is going to be between a and b and q is going to be between b and c, but I can't find a way to prove it.

Comment: Do you know Rolle’s Theorem?

Comment: Yes, I do. So, I can prove this by applying Rolle's theorem backward kinda?

Comment: Not backward. You *must* have stationary points between consecutive roots. But can there be others?

Answer (score 1):

Seeing that this is a direct corollary of rolle's theorom and you are asking to prove it, I assume you do not know any such theorems so I will extend upon your method of finding the derivative and proving from there.

First let us expand : $f(x) = x^3 - (a+b+c)x^2 + (ab+bc+ca)x - abc$

Now differentiating : $f'(x) = 3x^2 - 2(a+b+c)x + ab+bc+ca$

Now we have to prove that the roots of this equation (p and q) lie between c,b and b,a respectively.

This is indirectly IVT but I am expecting you know that if a quadratic function changes sign between two points i.e. $f(x_1) \cdot f(x_2) < 0$ then there exists a root $\alpha$ such that $x_1 < \alpha < x_2$ (layman proof : because of the fact that the quadratic function is continuous, it means that when it changes sign (like say -1 to 1) it has to attain all values between -1 and 1 so it has to attain $0$ and when it does, that x is what we call the root of the function)

So now with this knowledge, let us substitue c in f'(x) to get :

$f'(c) = 3c^2 - 2(a+b+c)c + ab + bc + ac \equiv 3c^2 - 2ac - 2bc - 2c^2 + ab + bc + ac \equiv c^2 - ac - bc + ab \equiv (c-a)(c-b)$

Since c > b > a, thus c - a & c - b are positve. Thus $f'(c) > 0$

Similiarly we get $f'(b) = (b-c)(b-a)$ but since c > b > a, thus b - a is positve and b - c is negative. Thus $f'(b) < 0$

And again $f'(a) = (a-c)(a-b)$ but since c > b > a, thus a - bis positve and a - c is negative. Thus $f'(a) > 0$

So we get $f'(c) \cdot f'(b) < 0 \;\&\; f'(a) \cdot f'(b) < 0$, and so a root of f'(x) must exist between b and c and between a and b. As q > p, It is q that exsts between b and c andd p that exists between a and b.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, I find the way you prove it brilliant. You explained it in such a simple and easy to understand fashion.

Comment: Thank you for that, I am kind of a beginner myself so I know the need of a thorough explanation, because it takes me too much time to understand how people do something when they don't explain it fully. Can you verify my answer if you found it to be correct and helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I will assume $a < b < c$. Since polynomials are differentiable, we can apply Rolle's theorem on the three known zeroes to conclude that there must be stationary points between $a$ and $b$ and between $b$ and $c$. By the fundamental theorem of algebra, a cubic polynomial can have at most two stationary points, as the stationary points occur at the zeroes of its derivative, which is a quadratic polynomial.